# Computer case access control?

Tags: server, case

Is it possible to know when someone open a computer case (hp server 1u), let's say in data center?

Inside server is usb port which can be used as some kind of switch.
That usb device would write to the syslog and automatically shutdown the server.

How can this be implemented easily? Any ideas?

Comment: You can't do that with an external device alone, you need some kind of sensor inside the case. It's probably easier (and less warranty-breaking) to get a case with that feature built in (it isn't uncommon on server hardware).

Comment: Sensor could be electronic switch. Which servers have this feature and how they call it ?